# How to print both Names & Sales inside of for-loop

Tags: kotlin

```
print("Enter size : ")
    val athleteSize : Int = readln().toInt()

    
var athleteName = ArrayList<String>()
    var athleteSale = ArrayList<Int>()



    println()
    println("Athlete Names: ")
    for(i in 1..athleteSize){
        print("Enter Athlete $i: ")
        athleteName.add(readln())

        print("Enter sales : ")
        athleteSale.add(readln().toInt())
        println()

    }
```

Sample Input:

```
Enter athlete 1: Pacman
Enter sales: 100

Enter athlete 2: Serena
Enter sales: 200
```

Sample output:

```
Pacman : 100
Serena : 100
Pacman : 200
Serena : 200
```

Expected output

```
Pacman : 100
Serena : 200
```

Comment: Where's your for loop where you're printing the output? You've only shown the input one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrList.last()` for getting the last index of ArrayList.

At the end of for loop use;

```
println("${athleteName.last()} ${athleteSale.last}")
```